# WinInet call HttpSendRequest doesn't pass auth information next time when I call it with the same connection handle

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wininet

I'm confused by the following problem I experience. We use **Windows 2008 R2** machine with **IE 8.0** installed. Next I try programmatically to connect to a server with **InternetConnect** call(auth credentials are provided as an arguments passed to it). It succeeds. Next I call **HttpOpenRequest** and **HttpSendRequest**. The calls to **HttpOpenRequest** and **HttpSendRequest** are performed using the same connection handle **InternetConnect** call returned. At some certain point of time **HttpSendRequest** begins to fail. From traffic capture I see there is auth info missing and it makes server in its turn to return **401** result. **InternetSetOption** call with **INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME** and **INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD** provided doesn't take any effect. After **HttpSendRequest** fails I call **GetLastError** and receive at first **ERROR_HTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE** and at second **ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE** if I try to re-send my request with **HttpSendRequest**.

Maybe somebody of you experienced similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it's a normal way of how client behaves. First it tries to contact resource anonymously and then if it fails it tries to use credentials. Within single function call it's ok to have one 401 result because the very next request comes along with auth credentials.

Comment: And what if you already know that you need to send Authentication headers? Is there anyway to force the request so it doesn't have to happen twice? That's a lot of overhead.

Comment: At the moment I stopped my investigation on this topic since I have no need in doing this anymore. But as far as I understand it is normal to set authentification data using WinINet. WinINet in it's turn makes first connection attempt w/o using a credentials you provided, but when a server responds with access denied it resends request with auth headers added. I realized this sequence happens during single WinINet connect call. So it happens transparently for API user in way that you may not want to get deepely in these details.